# Cannot find module 'coffee-script' using require grunt

Tags: node.js, nodes, node-webkit

Cannot find module 'coffee-script' using   grunt  from a script

```
          module.js:338
         throw err;
      ^
        Error: Cannot find module 'coffee-script'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Safa\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt.js:16:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

Comment: Have you ensured it's installed locally for the project? Try running `npm install coffee-script` and then running it again. I also recommend adding it to your [`package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) file if you haven't already, so in the future you can simply run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
npm install coffee-script#
```

and then running it again. It is recommended adding it to your `package.json` file if you haven't already, so in the future you can simply run

```
npm install
```